# Как мне сделать программу которая запрещает ввод букв?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string text = textBox1.Text;
        for (int cif2 = 0; cif2 < text.Length; cif2++) {
            for (int cif = 0; cif < 10; cif++)

                if (text[cif2] != Convert.ToChar(cif)) {
                    
                     


                    textBox1.Text = "" ;
                }
        }
```

Мне нужно сделать так что бы я не мог ввести в текстбокс буквы.Попытался сделать так как на верху пишет индекс за границами масива

Comment: Во-первых, отформатируйте код: уберите пустые строки, выровняйте его. Во-вторых, уточните, где вы использовали этот код, в каком месте/событии?

Comment: Какое отношение этот код имеет к самому вопросу? И конкретизируйте вопрос, вам нужен ввод только цифр, или чисел, дробных там, отрицательных и т.д. `NumericUpDown` пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два варианта решения этой задачи:

1. Использовать [NumericUpDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) он автоматически фильтрует вводимые данные и так же предоставляет пользователю использовать кнопки вверх вниз на клавиатуре, чтобы менять значение.
2. Отслеживать ивенты и предотвращать ввод любых не числовых значений:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Если вам нужно ограничить количество символов, которые пользователь может ввести в текст бокс доавьте эту строчку:
`textBox1.MaxLength = 2; // this will allow the user to enter only 2 digits`

Comment: а ему нужен запрет на буквы или запрет всех символов кроме цифр? Есть еще и спецсимволы. Да и в целом этот ответ практически дублирует мой.

Comment: :) Действительно, исключение букв не равнозначно вводу одних только чисел. К сожалению ваш ответ не решенает проблемы, которую озвучил автор, а лишь предоставляет пример, поэтому я решил написать свой)